# Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL 0.0.0.0:3000

Tags: javascript, node.js

I only want test in my host.

node -v 7.4.0
npm -v 4.0.5

```js
const http = require('http');
const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
const port = 3000;
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
        res.end('Hello World\n');
});
server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
        console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

when i try run my node.js. i get a error

[image]

Comment: that probably means something else is bound to port 3000 already.

Comment: try to execute sudo netstat -nlp and check listening ports

Comment: This question was asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809740/listen-eaddrnotavail-error-in-node-js

(I don't know how to mark as duplicate unfortunately, if I even can with my level of reputation)